# Сохраняются ли итераторы на элементы QList'а при его (QList'а) модификации?

Tags: c++, qt, list, список

Мне нужно удалить некоторые элементы из `QList`. Для ненужных элементов я создаю итераторы и помещаю их в отдельный контейнер `removing`.

```
// цикл для 'list'
QList<type>::iterator it = list.begin() + j;
removing.append(it);
// конец цикла для 'list'
```

...

```
while(removing.empty() == false)
{
    list.erase(removing.takeFirst());
}
```

В результате получается, когда в контейнере removing больше одного элемента, то первый элемент удаляется нормально, а на удалении второго возникает SEGMENTATION FAULT. 
При этом в отладчике QtCreator'а я вижу, что адреса в списке `list` не изменяются даже после удаления из середины `list`'а.

UPD Оказалось, для QList'а не гарантируется корректность итераторов при модификации контейнера: [Краткое описание QLinkedList](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html#the-container-classes) :

> (Iterators pointing to an item in a QLinkedList remain valid as long as the item exists, whereas iterators to a QList can become invalid after any insertion or removal.)

. Решил путём замены QList на QLinkedList. Правда, это вызывало несколько неудобств - в частности, пришлось переходить на итераторы для обхода списка, но зато работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При удалении элементов как-то делал так:

- Проходил по `списку1` и собирал индексы в `список2`
- Проходил по `списку2` с последнего элемента по первый (реверсированный список) и удалял из `списка1` по индексам
- Элементы удалялись без проблем